# Scroll rotated view in android

Tags: android, scroll, rotation, android-relativelayout

I am programming an Android app.

I have an activity with some EditTexts, a spinner and some buttons. The buttons are at the bottom of the layout.
When I rotate the emulator, the button at the bottom rotates off the bottom of the screen when it's in landscape, as it is not as tall. Is it possible to make the view scroll when it is in landscape, so I can reach the button. (I am using a relative layout).

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Have you tried putting it into a `ScrollView`?

Comment: I've tried adding in a scrollview, and then putting another relative layout with all my controls inside that. but it is not scrolling.

Comment: Sounds like you shouldn't be using a `RelativeLayout` then, but a `LinearLayout` instead.

Comment: I have a relative layout, with a scrollview inside, with a relative layout inside that, which one are you saying should be the linear layout?

Comment: `ScrollView` should be the top-level view, but if you want it to work properly, you should use a `LinearLayout` instead of `RelativeLayout` for your inner layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes it is possible ... use scrollview and every thing will be as you like
try this .. i guess it will help

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/layout_back"
    tools:context="eddine.charef.mechalikh.swipedemo.inscription" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView3"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView2"  >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="1"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="@string/infosGenerales"
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:background="#0061C2"
                android:textColor="#ffffffff" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/editNom"
                android:layout_weight="0.15"
                android:hint="@string/nom"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_2"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:selectAllOnFocus="false"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/editPrenom"
                android:layout_weight="0.15"
                android:hint="@string/prenom"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_2"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:selectAllOnFocus="false"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/editEmail"
                android:layout_weight="0.15"
                android:hint="@string/email"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_2"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:selectAllOnFocus="false"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/editPswrd"
                android:layout_weight="0.15"
                android:hint="@string/mdp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_2"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:selectAllOnFocus="false"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/editCnfrmPswrd"
                android:layout_weight="0.15"
                android:hint="@string/retapezMdp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_2"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:selectAllOnFocus="false"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp" />

            <Spinner
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/spinner4" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="@string/infosSurMedecin"
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:background="#0061C2"
                android:textColor="#ffffffff"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="date"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/editNum"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:hint="@string/numero"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_2"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:selectAllOnFocus="false"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp" />

            <Spinner
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/spinner5"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="@string/lieuxTravail"
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:background="#0061C2"
                android:textColor="#ffffffff"
                android:visibility="gone" />


            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/editAdresse"
                android:hint="@string/adresse"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_2"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:selectAllOnFocus="false"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="@string/position"
                android:id="@+id/tvPosition"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/choisirPosition"
                android:id="@+id/btnChoisirPos"
                android:onClick="btnChoisirPosClick"
                android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/inscription"
                android:id="@+id/btnInscri"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editNom"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/editNom"
                android:onClick="btnInscriClick"
                android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:textColor="#ffffffff"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_back" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="@string/avezVousUnCompte"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:onClick="textViewConnexClick"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:textColor="#ff0061c2"
        android:layout_weight="0.15"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" />



</RelativeLayout>
```